# Custom table view cell in IOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have custom `UITableViewCell`.
`UITableViewCell` have one `UILabel` and one `UIButton`. I want when click button then text of label change color to "redColor".
I don't process???

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: You want when you click button from cell1 -> change color of cell1, button cell2->change color in cell2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your custom table view cell set touch up inside event for the button like this

```
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In the same class add the following method

```
-(IBAction) clicked:(id)sender {
    [self.label setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Comment: i understand but when i click cell1 then text on cell3 change "redColor". text cell1 no change color. i want click the second text back "Black color"

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can do is maintain an array whose each element represents the corresponding row number.
 Initialize the array with 0 means all the label will have text color black. 
Now set the index of each button equal to index path.row in cell for row method .
 Now when the button is clicked set the value in array at index button.tag to 1 and others to 0 and reload tableview.
 Now in cell for row check if items in the array at index indexpath.row ==1 then set the color of uilabel to red else black.